# Setting up a project-level Jupyter Notebook Config file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, config, jupyter

I'd like my Jupyter Server to use a different `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file for each of my projects. Currently, my `jupyter_notebook_config.py` resides in my `~/.jupyter/` directory. Ideally, I'd like to be able to put a project-specific version of the config file in the root directory of each project and have Jupyter Server load it from there. How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3):

You could set the `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR` variable to being each project's root folder whenever running a Jupyter server for that project.

https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html#configuration-files